# Finding if text is before or after child

Tags: xpath, xslt

Currently trialling Anteena House Formatter and am looking at using MathML in it but I've come up against a bit of a snag.

To save having massive chunks of code here the following 3 are examples of what might appear in my xml code.

```
<form>starting text x <frac><num>numerator</num><den>denominator</den></frac></form>
<form>starting text x <frac><num>numerator</num><den>denominator</den></frac> x ending text</form>
<form><frac><num>numerator</num><den>denominator</den></frac> x only ending text</form>
```

The template for frac just picks out the value of num and den and outputs them as a fraction. I also had the start of the form template picking out the text and putting it into mtext before the fraction. The issue is there may be text before the fraction, after it or both.
Where there is both i can use xsl:value-of select="./text()[1]"  to select the first piece and xsl:value-of select="./text()[2]"  to get what I need. The problem is where there is only text at the start or end and identifying which side it is on. does anyone have any ideas on how I can identify if the string is before or after the frac tag?
TIA

Comment: Usually, with any XSLT, just use template matching an apply-templates and the order of your input is preserved e.g. whatever your template(s) for e.g. `form/text()` transform the text nodes to will appear before the result of the template matching `frac` if the text node is before the `frac` and after it if the text node is after the `frac`. Of course you can also check e.g. `text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::frac]]`.

Comment: I hadn't really thought about hiving off the processing of the text itself to another template. I'll give that a go. Thanks